# PHP open_basedir error

Tags: php, installation

Been trying to install php today and I ran into this problem when trying to launch my website:

```
PHP Warning:  session_start(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\Windows\TEMP) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\website) in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\website\bootstrap.php on line 21
```

I have set my php.ini to the following settings:

```
open_basedir = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\website\"
```

and

```
upload_tmp_dir = "C:\Windows\TEMP\"
```

I tried changing the directory for `upload_temp_dir` to `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\website\temp` but the error keeps telling me that `C:\Windows\TEMP` is not valid - even though I changed the dir.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

EDIT:

Now I am getting:

```
PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(C:\Windows\TEMP\\sess_ca0ea257d89dfecd355e375071e30d7e, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\website\bootstrap.php on line 21
```

PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(C:\Windows\TEMP\sess_ca0ea257d89dfecd355e375071e30d7e, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (C:\Windows\TEMP) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: after you change the upload_tmp_dir, did you restart the apache service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`open_basedir` limits the files that can be opened by PHP within a directory-tree.

You should config session.save-path to some path inside

`C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\website\`

Or add the session directory to the list of folders that PHP script can access

`session.save-path = "C:\Windows\TEMP\"`

`open_basedir = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\website\;C:\Windows\TEMP\"`

Comment: Ok now I am getting Permission denied. I tried both approaches.

Comment: Does the account that your web server is running have write permissions on C:\Windows\Temp ?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:  I had to remove the quotes from the open_basedir path on Windows 10, PHP 7.3 (in the php.ini file)

Does not work: `open_basedir = "C:\Windows\TEMP\;C:\Some\Other\Path\"`

Works `open_basedir = C:\Windows\TEMP\;C:\Some\Other\Path\`